# Failed to save video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

Using OpenCV, I have been extracting the frames from a video and after working on the frames, I have been trying to save them to a new video file. But the new video file is not being saved properly. It gets saved as 0 KB in size and throws the following error when I try to open it.
[OpenCV Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54y9.png)

My code is as follows:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Path to source video")

out = cv2.VideoWriter("Path to save video", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"VIDX"), 5, (1000, 1200))

print(cap.isOpened())
while True:

     # Capture frame-by-frame
     ret, frame = cap.read()

     # Write the video
     out.write(frame)

     # Display the resulting frame
     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to follow the solution [Can't save a video in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689660/cant-save-a-video-in-opencv) but it did not help in my case.

Comment: `VIDX` is not a valid codec. `assert out.isOpened()` would have been False, right? and what's the size (width, height) of your source video?

Comment: I used the answer given below ( took source video's height (1000) and width (1920)), but still didn't work. I also tried changing the codec to "XVID".

Answer (score 0):

when saving the file, your width and height should match with frame's width and height, so in order to get the width and height of the frame automatically, use

```html
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) # to get width of the frame
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) # to get height of the frame

out = cv2.VideoWriter("dummy_video.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"VIDX"), 5, (width, height))

print(cap.isOpened())
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Write the video
    out.write(frame)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried it, but It's not working.

Comment: It should work. Could you provide the video that you are working on..!